# Imported Eclipse Project Won't compile

Tags: eclipse

When exporting eclipse projects, then importing them at another location, eclipse shows a red exclamation mark. There are no errors in the code itself, as it compiled and ran with no issues before exporting.

When I try to compile it, it says there are errors in the project, and I select proceed.
Then I get the error:"no main class def found", as none of the files were re-compiled, and thus no .class files exist in /bin directory.

I am cloning from github.

How do I resolve this?

SOLVED:

After going into problem view, I found the issue was unrelated to my current project, althought Eclipse got confused and showed it thus. It was a buildpath issue with a missing external jar I had linked in another project.

Thanks Mliebelt

Comment: Open the problems view in eclipse, and copy the content of the error there in for your project. Normally, it tells you the reason for the error, and most of the times, it is sufficient to come one step further. Edit your answer and include the real error there in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With so few informations, just do Project > Clean... (with "build automatically" checked).

For a better answer, you should tell us what the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you aren't sitting in a build class directory at a command prompt that Eclipse is trying to remove.